# Reverse Engineering a Perl script based on a core dump

Tags: perl, reverse-engineering

A friend's server (yes, really. Not mine.) was broken into and we discovered a perl binary running some bot code. We could not find the script itself (probably eval'ed as received over the network), but we managed to create a core dump of the perl process.

Running strings on the core gave us some hints (hostnames, usernames / passwords), but not the source code of the script.

We'd like to know what the script was capable of doing, so we'd like to reverse-engineer the perl code that was running inside that perl interpreter.

Searching around, the closest thing to a perl de-compiler I found is the B::Deparse module which seems to be perfectly suitable for converting the bytecode of the parse-trees back into readable code.

Now, how do I get B::Deparse to operate on a core dump? Or, alternatively, how could I restart the program from the core, load B::Deparse and execute it?

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ysth asked me on IRC to comment on your question. I've done a whole
pile of stuff "disassembling" compiled perl and stuff (just see my
CPAN page [http://search.cpan.org/~jjore]).

Perl compiles your source to a tree of `OP*` structs which
occasionally have C pointers to `SV*` which are perl values. Your core
dump now has a bunch of those `OP*` and `SV*` stashed.

The best possible world would be to have a perl module like
[B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) do the information-understanding work for you. It
works by using a light interface to perl memory in the `B::OP` and
`B::SV` classes (documented in [B](http://perldoc.perl.org/B.html), [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html), and
[perlhack](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhack.html)). This is unrealistic for you because a `B::*` object is
just a pointer into memory with accessors to decode the struct for our
use. Consider:

```
require Data::Dumper;
require Scalar::Util;
require B;

my $value = 'this is a string';

my $sv      = B::svref_2object( \ $value );
my $address = Scalar::Util::refaddr( \ $value );

local $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
local $Data::Dumper::Purity   = 1;
print Data::Dumper::Dumper(
  {
    address => $address,
    value   => \ $value,
    sv      => $sv,
    sv_attr => {
      CUR           => $sv->CUR,
      LEN           => $sv->LEN,
      PV            => $sv->PV,
      PVBM          => $sv->PVBM,
      PVX           => $sv->PVX,
      as_string     => $sv->as_string,
      FLAGS         => $sv->FLAGS,
      MAGICAL       => $sv->MAGICAL,
      POK           => $sv->POK,
      REFCNT        => $sv->REFCNT,
      ROK           => $sv->ROK,
      SvTYPE        => $sv->SvTYPE,
      object_2svref => $sv->object_2svref,
    },
  }
);
```

which when run showed that the `B::PV` object (it is ISA `B::SV`) is
truely merely an interface to the memory representation of the
compiled string `this is a string`.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'address' => 438506984,
          'sv' => bless( do{\(my $o = 438506984)}, 'B::PV' ),
          'sv_attr' => {
                         'CUR' => 16,
                         'FLAGS' => 279557,
                         'LEN' => 24,
                         'MAGICAL' => 0,
                         'POK' => 1024,
                         'PV' => 'this is a string',
                         'PVBM' => 'this is a string',
                         'PVX' => 'this is a string',
                         'REFCNT' => 2,
                         'ROK' => 0,
                         'SvTYPE' => 5,
                         'as_string' => 'this is a string',
                         'object_2svref' => \'this is a string'
                       },
          'value' => do{my $o}
        };
$VAR1->{'value'} = $VAR1->{'sv_attr'}{'object_2svref'};
```

This however implies that any `B::*` using code must actually operate
on live memory. Tye McQueen thought he remembered a C debugger which
could fully revive a working process given a core dump. My `gdb`
can't. `gdb` can allow you to dump the contents of your `OP*` and
`SV*` structs. You would most likely just read the dumped structs to
interpret your program's structure. You could, if you wished, use
`gdb` to dump the structs, then synthetically create `B::*` objects
which behaved in interface as if they were ordinary and use
`B::Deparse` on that. At root, our deparser and other debug dumping
tools are mostly object oriented so you could just "fool" them by
creating a pile of fake `B::*` classes and objects.

You may find reading the B::Deparse class's `coderef2text` method
instructive. It accepts a function reference, casts it to a `B::CV`
object, and uses that for input to the `deparse_sub` method:

```
require B;
require B::Deparse;
sub your_function { ... }

my $cv = B::svref_2object( \ &your_function );
my $deparser = B::Deparse->new;
print $deparser->deparse_sub( $cv );
```

For gentler introductions to `OP*` and related ideas, see the updated
[PerlGuts Illustrated](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/illguts-0.33/index-12.html) and [Optree guts](https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/index.cgi?optree_guts).

Comment: Josh,

thanks for the detailed answer. This pretty much jives with what I expected. Looks like a project for long winter nights.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there's a tool out there that does this out of the box, so...

1. Find the source code to the version of perl you were running. This should help you understand the memory layout of the perl interpreter. It will also help you figure out if there's a way to take a shortcut here (e.g. if bytecode is preceded by an easy to find header in memory or something).
2. Load up the binary + core dump in a debugger, probably gdb
3. Use the information in the perl source code to guide you in convincing the debugger to spit out the bytecode you're interested in.

Once you have the bytecode, B::Deparse should be able to get you to something more readable.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable. 

There might be a catch, though: The perl documentation refers to the byte code as parse-tree. This suggests that the byte-code is not an array of op-codes that is independent of its address in memory. Instead, this sound like some sort of tree with pointers and perhaps even pointers towards code implementing primitives.

I'm thus not sure whether B::Deparse can cope with a parse-tree that was generated by a different perl instance.

Comment: Looking at the Deparse code shows another problem:

Deparse oeprated on the perl objects representing the program, and not the memory/byte-stream that stores that code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [undump](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) will turn that core dump back into a binary executable (if you can find a working version). You should then be able to load that into `perl` and `-MO=Deparse` it.

Comment: Err, I think there's a flaw there; how do you load a binary executable into perl?

Comment: I was under the impression I'd just done `perl a.out` one of these days following a Par::Packer tutorial, but I tried it now and it didn't work.